# css BEM - do we really need the E?

Tags: html, css, bem

So I am working on a very large e-commerce site, only been on it a short time and the project was developed a year ago.
Im thinking to refactor the css as it seems to have got out of hand...and I was wondering if we really need to use the E in css BEM methodology.

So long as you have sufficiently distinct sections of the site, cant all buttons for example inherit from the block button class and just use a modifier class to theme them differently...seems simpler and then you don't create any dependencies on a button being used in different sections of the site?

Comment: Do we really need the B and the M either? Anyway, watch out, if you start using heretical concepts like inheritance and modifier classes the BEM police may come and take you away.

Comment: @torazaburo I'd watch out for those guys, I know people doing time for that kinda thing...

Answer (score 3):

**You don't *"really"* need any of BEM.**

At the end of the day it comes down to what you are most comfortable with. If you feel that doing things a certain / different way will benefit you, then hey.. It's 2016 go crazy!

---

**EDIT**: It's now 2017, you can still go crazy...

**EDIT**: It's now 2018, you can still go crazy...